# Finding grouped records in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am having a query regarding the grouping of certain values and inserting the data into a different table based on the grouping.

The table name is DETAILS2. The table looks like this:

```
NUM2    MAT_NUM     TRAVEL_DT     TRAVEL_TYP       TRAVEL_REQ

1-7OR   Rail        11-OCT-2016     Train          2

1-7OR   Ground      12-OCT-2016     Bus            2

1-7OR   Fly         15-0CT-2016     Flight         1

1-72R   Rail        11-SEP-2016     Train          2

1-72R   Ground      12-SEP-2016     Bus            3

1-72R   Fly         15-SEP-2016     Flight         1
```

I need to first group by NUM2, MAT_NUM and then by TRAVEL_REQ.

1. If I find MAT_NUM is Rail or Ground with the same TRAVEL_REQ, then I need to insert only one record into another table.
2. If I find MAT_NUM is Rail or Ground with the different TRAVEL_REQ, then I need to insert two records into another table.
3. If I find MAT_NUM is Fly, then I need to insert only one record into another table.

In order to achieve this, I wrote the following code first. But it is inserting all the records. Could you help me modify the code?

```
    DECLARE

    NUM1    VARCHAR2(50);
    NXTNUM1 VARCHAR2(50);
    DECIDER   VARCHAR2(10);
    TYP1   VARCHAR2(50);

    CURSOR FET_TYP
    IS
    SELECT DISTINCT NUM2,
           LEAD(NUM2) OVER (ORDER BY NUM2),
           CASE WHEN DET.MAT_NUM NOT LIKE '%Fly%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DECIDER,
           MAT_NUM
    FROM   DETAILS2
    ORDER BY NUM2;

    BEGIN
    OPEN FET_TYP;
    LOOP

    FETCH FET_TYP
    INTO  NUM1,
          NXTNUM1,
          DECIDER,
          TYP1;

    EXIT WHEN FET_TYP%NOTFOUND;

    IF ((NUM1 = NXTNUM1) AND (DECIDER = 0))
    THEN  

    INSERT INTO TEMP1
    VALUES (NUM1, TYP1, 'Ground');

    ELSIF ((NUM1 = NXTNUM1) AND (DECIDER = 1))
    THEN

    INSERT INTO TEMP1
    VALUES (NUM1, TYP1, 'Flight');

    END IF;

    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;

    CLOSE FET_TYP;

    END;
```

Here is what the final output looks like.

```
NUM2    MAT_NUM     TRAVEL_DT     TRAVEL_TYP       TRAVEL_REQ

1-7OR   Ground      12-OCT-2016     Bus            2

1-7OR   Fly         15-0CT-2016     Flight         1

1-72R   Rail        11-SEP-2016     Train          2

1-72R   Ground      12-SEP-2016     Bus            3

1-72R   Fly         15-SEP-2016     Flight         1
```

These are the primary column output along with some default values which I will insert while writing the insert statement. The first record can be Rail or Ground. Doesn't matter when TRAVEL_REQ has the same value.

Comment: This maybe doable without cursors. Can you edit your post with expected results in TEMP1?

Comment: In your first condition (1.) - WHICH record should be inserted? It is not enough to say "only one", you must state which one. Then: What is inserted in the "other table" - the rows from this table, with the same columns? Or only some of the columns? Or something entirely different? Another question: What do you mean by condition (3.)? For 1-70R you have all three types. One of them is FLY. Does that mean you insert only one row out of all three rows? And if so, which one? (What if travel_req is different in the other two rows - this will contradict condition 2.)

Comment: 1. Anyone can be inserted.
2. For 1-7OR , I insert 2 records because the TRAVEL_REQ is the same. For 1-72R, I insert 3 records because the TRAVEL_REQ is different for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `row_number` function per your conditions.

```
select num2,mat_num,travel_dt,travel_typ,travel_req 
from (select d.*
      ,row_number() over(partition by num2,travel_req order by travel_req,mat_num) rn
      from details2 d
     ) x
where rn = 1
```

Use the returned result-set to `insert` the required columns to a different table.

Comment: Hi vkp, Thanks or your answer. One of my colleague also suggested this. However if we are using this, then the condition on MAT_NUM is ignored and the result set will be different for '1-72R' record because we are only partitioning by NUM2 and not on MAT_NUM

Comment: I did a UNION ALL and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot vkp !

select num2,mat_num,travel_dt,travel_typ,travel_req 
from (select d.*
      ,row_number() over(partition by num2,travel_req order by travel_req,mat_num where MAT_NUM  not like '%Fly%) rn
      from details2 d
     ) x
where rn = 1
UNION ALL
select num2,mat_num,travel_dt,travel_typ,travel_req 
from (select d.*
      ,row_number() over(partition by num2,travel_req order by travel_req,mat_num where MAT_NUM  like '%Fly%) rn
      from details2 d
     ) x
where rn = 1